# How to sort and get a desired number in an array

Tags: vb.net

So, as the title says, I need to be able to sort an array of randomly generated numbers and also have the user choose the number they want to roll, say they want to roll a 4, they will input a 4 in a textbox and there will be a label somewhere on the form telling the user how many times that number showed up, I just can't seem to figure it out though, how to sort and how to get that probability, any help?

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Class Chcked


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub cmdGenerate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGenerate.Click
        ' Initialize the random-number generator.
        Dim strOutput As String

        Dim intArray(Val(txtFirst.Text)) As Integer
        Dim Counter As Integer
        Dim Random As Integer
        For Counter = 1 To Val(txtFirst.Text)

            Randomize()
            Random = Int(Rnd() * 6) + 1

            intArray(txtFirst.Text) = Random


            strOutput = intArray(txtFirst.Text)
            txtSequence.Text = " " & strOutput & " " + txtSequence.Text & " "

        Next Counter



    End Sub

    Private Sub Clear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click
        txtSequence.Text = " "
    End Sub

    Private Sub Sort_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Sort.Click

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You are using the user input as the number of randoms rather than the target value in a set of N randoms.  Code seems to be different than the question

Comment: I forgot to mention that, I have the user enter the amount of numbers they want generated, then in another textbox have them choose the number they want...if that makes any more sense

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx ?

Comment: The `Randomize()` statement is on the wrong line: it should be just afer the `' Initialize the random-number generator.` comment. Otherwise the random number generator may well be initialised to the same value more than once in succession in the loop. Actually, it might as well be in the `Form1_Load` method.

Comment: You should use [`Option Strict On`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - it will tell you about problems with the types of data in your code, e.g. trying to use a string where there should be an integer.